# Share structure between GraphQL schemas

Tags: graphql, relay, graphql-js, apollo, react-apollo

I have a Apollo GraphQL server talking to an API returning responses with roughly the following structure:

```
{
  "pagination": {
    "page": 1,
    // more stuff
  },
  sorting: {
    // even more stuff
  },
  data: [ // Actual data ]
}
```

This structure is going to be shared across pretty much all responses from this API, that I'm using extensively. `data` is going to be an array most of the time, but can also be an object.

How can I write this in an efficient way, so that I don't have to repeat all these `pagination` and `sorting` fields on every data type in my schemas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define your schema, you will end up abstracting out pagination, sorting, etc. as separate types. So the schema will look something like:

```
type Bar {
  pagination: Pagination
  sorting: SortingOptions
  data: BarData # I'm an object
}
type Foo {
  pagination: Pagination
  sorting: SortingOptions
  data: [FooData] # I'm an array
}
# more types similar to above
type Pagination {
  page: Int
  # more fields
}
type SortingOptions {
  # more fields
}
type BarData {
  # more fields
}
```

So you **won't** have to list each field within Pagination multiple times regardless. Each type that uses Pagination, however, will still need to specify it as a field -- there's no escaping that requirement.

Alternatively, you could set up a single Type to use for all your objects. In this case, the data field would be an Interface (Data), with FooData, BarData, etc. each implementing it. In your resolver for Data, you would define a __resolveType function to determine which kind of Data to return. You can pass in a typename variable with your query and then use that variable in the __resolveType function to return the correct type.

You can see a good example of Interface in action in the [Apollo docs](http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-tools/resolvers.html#Unions-and-interfaces).

The downside to this latter approach is that you have to return either a single Data object or an Array of them -- you can't mix and match -- so you would probably have to change the structure of the returned object to make it work.

Comment: Thanks you for your time. Actually I thought of those two ways before, but the first one forces me to repeat the `sorting` and `pagination` every time, and also forces me to create a `Foo` AND a `FooData` for every type, which is quite ugly and painful.
This is still the solution I was going with though, because the second one would force me to write a really huge `resolveType` function considering all the different types I have. I was looking for a third way, I guess there isn't one.

Comment: This is kind of a stretch, but you could look into something like [json-to-graphql](https://github.com/aweary/json-to-graphql). Write out an array of objects, with just the data field specified for each one. Then use reduce to both insert the sorting and pagination fields and convert the array to an object. This would be probably easier/shorter to write, but I imagine the resulting schema might also be less readable than your current approach.

Comment: I've had the same challenge, and I sorted out by creating a lib called graphql-s2s which allows enhancing your schema to support inheritance and generic types. Have a look at Part II of this article where I describe how you would solve this exact problem: https://hackernoon.com/graphql-schemas-easier-better-structure-31677a640d18

Answer (score 5):

I've sorted your problem by creating a lib called [graphql-s2s](https://github.com/nicolasdao/graphql-s2s). It enhances your schema by adding support for type inheritance, generic types and metadata. In your case, creating a generic type for your Paginated object could be a viable solution. Here is an example:

```
const { transpileSchema } = require('graphql-s2s')
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('graphql-tools')

const schema = `
type Paged<T> {
    data: [T]
    cursor: ID
}
type Node {
    id: ID!
    creationDate: String
}
type Person inherits Node {
    firstname: String!
    middlename: String
    lastname: String!
    age: Int!
    gender: String 
}
type Teacher inherits Person {
    title: String!
}
type Student inherits Person {
    nickname: String!
    questions: Paged<Question>
}
type Question inherits Node {
    name: String!
    text: String!
}
type Query {

  students: Paged<Student>

  teachers: Paged<Teacher>
}
`

const executableSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: [transpileSchema(schema)],
  resolvers: resolver
})
```

I've written more details about this [here](https://hackernoon.com/graphql-schemas-easier-better-structure-31677a640d18) (in Part II).